# First few microsoft translator API requests succeed , then the calls fails and throws NoArgument exception with invalid appid

Tags: java, azure, azure-cognitive-services, bing-translator-api

I am using Microsoft translator api, i have registered my app to datamarket and got the clientid and clientsecret. My api request succeed for few times . Now i am getting noArgument exceptio  with

**NoArgumentException: Invalid appId
Parameter name: appId : ID=1116.V2_Json.Translate.4EEF7E6A - Row_IDArgumentException: Invalid appId**

Please let me know in case i have missed something.

Answer (score 1):

Sam, you are using the older DataMarket APIs which are being deprecated.  You should upgrade to use the Azure Cognitive Service APIs which use an authentication token instead of the client secret.  Step by step instructions are documented at http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html, or you can see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/ for all of the APIs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you used a java library `microsoft-translator-java-api` wrappered an old MS Translator API which comes from https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/microsofttranslator. As @kwill said and the information from the old website, as below.

> **THE MICROSOFT TRANSLATOR API IS NOW AVAILABLE ON THE AZURE PORTAL**

You can follow the first link of @kwill post to know how to use the new API, or refer to my answer for an existing SO thread [MS Translator returns empty response when used with Azure token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946901/ms-translator-returns-empty-response-when-used-with-azure-token/41948725) using the new MS translator API on Azure to try it, but you need to have an Azure subscription to create a Translator Text API service like below.

[image]