# Bing translator exception while integrating with java application

Tags: java, azure, bing-translator-api

I am trying to integrate bing translator in my java application. I have registered to Microsoft azure cognitive service and Microsoft market place.
while executing below code

```
import com.memetix.mst.language.Language;
import com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Translate.setClientId(/* my Client Id */);
            Translate.setClientSecret(/* my Client Secret */);

            String translatedText = Translate.execute("Bonjour le monde", Language.FRENCH, Language.ENGLISH);

            System.out.println(translatedText);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting below exception:

```
Page NoException in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: [microsoft-translator-api] Error retrieving translation : Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13
    at com.memetix.mst.MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.retrieveString(MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.java:202)
    at com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate.execute(Translate.java:61)
    at test.SimpleExcelTranalator.main(SimpleExcelTranalator.java:44)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.memetix.mst.MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.getToken(MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.java:139)
    at com.memetix.mst.MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.retrieveResponse(MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.java:160)
    at com.memetix.mst.MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.retrieveString(MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.java:199)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.memetix.mst.MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.getToken(MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.java:138)
    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 1):

The datamarket url is where you get your client id and secret from. Is that where you're sending your translation request to? Should be something like
http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?

Also datamarket is being deprecated. You have to switch to Azure Cognitive Services
http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html

Answer (score 0):

According to your referenced package `com.memetix.mst.language.*` in your code, I searched and found its source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/boatmeme/microsoft-translator-java-api), repository on [Maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.memetix/microsoft-translator-java-api), and an old repository on [GoogleCode](https://code.google.com/archive/p/microsoft-translator-java-api/). I reviewed its source code, and discovered it wrappered the MS Translator Text API from [Azure old datamarket web site](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/microsofttranslator). The library is out of date with the old REST API, the old website shows "**THE MICROSOFT TRANSLATOR API IS NOW AVAILABLE ON THE AZURE PORTAL**" and "**IMPORTANT**: An Azure account is required. Read the steps to get started on the portal [here](http://aka.ms/TranslatorAzureMigration)." So first you need to have an Azure subscription to create a Translator Text API service on Azure portal, then write code to call the new REST API. You can refer to my answer for the two other SO threads as below to know how to use the new REST API and call it via my sample code.

1. My answer for [MS Translator returns empty response when used with Azure token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946901/ms-translator-returns-empty-response-when-used-with-azure-token/41948725) shows the new REST API usage.
2. My answer for [Microsoft Translator API Java, How to get client new ID with Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42891510/microsoft-translator-api-java-how-to-get-client-new-id-with-azure/42898852#42898852) which includes my sample code, it shows how to call the new REST API in Java.

Hope it helps.