# Microsoft Translator API from Java with Azure

Tags: java, api, azure, translation

I'm trying to call the Microsoft Translator API from Java using the new Azure Cloud methods that were introduced in May 2017.

I had been using this API from Java very successfully before then, but now with this new change something seems to be broken. I see that something has changed with the authentication and it must be recoded.

I'm sure someone has a good working example of test code. Can anyone help out here?

Comment: Can you post your old code?

Comment: There's no point, it won't work anymore. It used the excellent memetix library for MS Translator which made translating things super simple.Well at least it used to. Now it just gives errors because of MS's changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my answers for other similar SO threads, which include the explaination for these changes and Java sample codes for new MS Translator API version, as below.

1. [Bing translator exception while integrating with java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43115544/bing-translator-exception-while-integrating-with-java-application/43178769#43178769)
2. [MS Translator returns empty response when used with Azure token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946901/ms-translator-returns-empty-response-when-used-with-azure-token/41948725)
3. [Microsoft Translator API Java, How to get client new ID with Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42891510/microsoft-translator-api-java-how-to-get-client-new-id-with-azure/42898852#42898852)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had seen these previously, but didn't completely understand what was going on. I was finally able to get this to work by hacking together some of this code along with code I grabbed from github to use the MS Speech Translation API (I used their version of creating tokens).